# Batch/ tab files to csv

Tags: batch-file

I need help creating a batch file that will convert tab delimited files to csv. I have 4seperate files that a tab delimited that i need to be csv.

Comment: You should always show what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

From the scant data you've given,

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (tdf.txt) DO (
 SET line=%%i
 SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
 ECHO(!line:    =,!
 endlocal
)
) >csv.txt
```

This should do the job.

The meat of the matter is in the `ECHO` line which changes all tabs (the character after the colon) to commas (the character string after the `=`) producing a new file `csv.txt` from the old one `tdf.txt`

Comment: Why is there a `(` after the `echo`?  Is that a typo?

Comment: @Nate Not a typo - quite calculated, in fact. It's one of many symbols which may directly follow `echo` and still perform the `echo` function. Traditionally, the following character is a space but this breaks with `echo [nothing]` which reports the `ECHO` status. Conventionally, `ECHO.` has been used to produce a new empty line. Other characters like `,;=` can also be used - and understandably since these are command-separators. But there are others like `/\+([` that can also be used to exploit the `echo.` characteristic - followed by text or no. Of these, `(` appears to be the most reliable.